# Spark: strange nullPointerException when extracting data from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.6 and Spark 2.0.0

I want to create a `DataFrame` form a postgreSQL table, as following:

```
val query =
  """(
        SELECT events.event_facebook_id,
          places.placeid, places.likes as placelikes,
          artists.facebookId, artists.likes as artistlikes
          FROM events

        LEFT JOIN eventsplaces on eventsplaces.event_id = events.event_facebook_id
          LEFT JOIN places on eventsplaces.event_id = places.facebookid
        LEFT JOIN eventsartists on eventsartists.event_id = events.event_facebook_id
          LEFT JOIN artists on eventsartists.artistid = artists.facebookid) df"""
```

The request is valid (if I run it on psql, I don't get any error) but with Spark, 
if I execute the following code, I get a `NullPointerException`:

```
sqlContext
      .read
      .format("jdbc")
      .options(
        Map(
          "url" -> claudeDatabaseUrl,
          "dbtable" -> query))
      .load()
      .show()
```

If I change, in the query `artists.facebookId` by an other column as `artists.description` (which can be `null` contrary to `facebookId`), the exception disappears.

I find this very very strange, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have different `facebookId`'s in your query: `artists.facebook[I]d` and `artists.facebook[i]d`.

Please, try to use the correct one.

Comment: Thanks but PosgreSQL queries are case insensitive